# Relationship to choose correct language from database

Tags: php, laravel, model

My code is based on this code [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305111/how-to-create-a-database-driven-multi-level-navigation-menu-using-laravel/21309815#21309815).

I have 3 tables for navigation (this is migration):

```
    Schema::create('navigation_positions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
    });

    Schema::create('navigation', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->string('icon')->nullable();
        $table->string('url')->nullable();
        $table->integer('sort')->nullable()->default(NULL);
        $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('position_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('position_id')->references('id')->on('navigation_positions')
            ->onDelete('restrict');

    });

    Schema::create('navigation_translate', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->integer('navigation_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('language_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('navigation_id')->references('id')->on('navigation')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('language_id')->references('id')->on('languages')
            ->onDelete('restrict');
    });
```

I will insert record into `navigation` and because my website is multilingual (stored `language_id` in `language` session) I will store translated language in `navigation_translate`.

I want to select the correct record from `navigation_translate` according to my `language_id` and `navigation_positions.slug`.

For example this is my records:

`navigation_positions` :

```
["id" => 1, "slug" => "admin-sidebar"]
```

`navigation_translate` :

```
["id" => 1, "title" => "User Management", "navigation_id" => 1, "language_id" => 1]
```

I want to select all parents and children in `admin-sidebar` position with `language_id = 1`

Answer (score 0):

I think that might be a correct answer if I understand the question. The `with()` method allows you to eager load a relationship:

```
NavigationPosition::where('slug','some-slug')
    ->with(['navigation' => function ($query) {
        $query->with(['navigationTranslate' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('language_id',1);
        }]);
    }])->get();
```

Référence: [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: Thanks, but not work for me :( I want to select records from 3 tables at the same time

Comment: I edited my response, you could try something like this (not tested)