# How to design a database for types and categories in Laravel?

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, database-design

As the questions states, what is the best way when designing a database for types and categories?

**Scenario:**

I have x amount of database-tables e.g. users, feedback, facts and countries, and all these tables have a type-attribute. What I've found is that a lot of people tend to just create type-tables for each and one of these. E.g. user_types, feedback_types, fact_types and country_types.

I'm currently working on a project where I don't want to create a bunch of extra tables just to handle their individual types. Therefore I'm trying to come up with a database-design-solution that fits all tables.

**My best thought of solution:**

At first I thought I might just create a polymorphic table that has *id*, *type_id*, *typable_id* and *typable_type* and a types table. Then i figured that I have to specify in the types table which type-attribute belongs to which table. Then it hit me, I can create a self-referencing table where the parent name is the table name.

E.g.

```
---------------------------------------------
|id | parent_id | name        | description |
---------------------------------------------
| 1 | null      | feedback    | something   |
---------------------------------------------
| 2 | 1         | general     | something   |
---------------------------------------------
| 3 | 1         | bug         | something   |
---------------------------------------------
| 4 | 1         | improvement | something   |
---------------------------------------------
| 5 | null      | countries   | something   |
---------------------------------------------
| 4 | 5         | europe      | something   |
---------------------------------------------
| 4 | 5         | asia        | something   |
---------------------------------------------
| etc...                                    |
---------------------------------------------
```

Is this a ok design? I'm thinking a lot about the parent names in this table, I haven't seen anyone else use table-names as parents.

If thinking about it in a front-end point of view, it's easier to get the correct types depending on which types you're looking for.

Please give me feedback on this. I'm struggling to find a good design.

Comment: You can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305111/how-to-create-a-database-driven-multi-level-navigation-menu-using-laravel

Comment: @NitishKumar I'm aware of how self-referencing designs works. What I'm trying to figure out is if my description is a good design. I mean, where I use the parent name as table name to easier find which types that belongs to which table.