# Laravel multilevel menus with sorting

Tags: laravel, menu, laravel-5.5

I need your help with multilevel menu created in laravel, also with an opinion to sort. 
I have database structure like this:
[image]

`structure_id` is primary key. `structure_name` is a name, which will be display on front-end. `structure_url` is url, which the anchor will point to. `module_id` is irrelevant here (need for my uses inside app). `sort_position` is important. It's integer from 1 to x. I will order the menu items asc/desc by this number. I also need to have an opinion to change order (I think I could be able to code it myself... I hope). I have really no idea, what to do with sort_position while in submenus...
`parent_id` is an attribute, which says, menu item has a parent in the other menu item. So if this value is 0 (like default), the item is up. If the item's parent_id is f.e.: 2, it means, the item belongs under structure_id = 2

I have tried some futile experiments, but I have no chance to do it myself. I am really beginner in laravel, so I hope anyone could help me

Comment: What's the problem? You can specify the order (sort_position) manually, when adding / editing a menu item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the step by step I'm using to get multilevel menus :

> Table "menus"

id, title, order, parent_id

> Model

```
class Menu extends Model
{
    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class , 'parent_id', 'id')->orderBy('order');
    }
}
```

> Controller

```
class MenuController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $menus = Menu::where('parent_id', 0)->orderBy('order', 'ASC')->get();
        return view('menu', compact('menus'));
    }
}
```

> View

```
@foreach($menus as $menu)
    @foreach($menu->children => $child)
        <h4>{{ $child->title }}</h4>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Doesn't work bro. Could you please add full step-by-step tutorial, how to do it? I'm really new to laravel :(

Comment: I did something by this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305111/how-to-create-a-database-driven-multi-level-navigation-menu-using-laravel however I get always empty array as a result. What's wrong? :(

Comment: @MegoSoft, please see my update step by step to get multilevel meus.

Comment: Thank you a lot. It was helpfull. I have just one question. $menus = Menu::where('parent_id', 0)->orderBy('order', 'ASC')->get(); Is it possible to add ->join() here? I need to connect to another table to get modul name.

Comment: Yes, you can. But you must specific Menu ID in select.

Comment: I received modul names only for parent items :O How to get them also on children?

Comment: I tried this: public function children() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Navigation', 'parent_id', 'structure_id')->join('modules', 'modules.module_id', '=', 'structure.module_id');
    } and it works!