# multilevel menu in laravel with recursive function

Tags: php, laravel, recursion, menu

my project is in Laravel 5.5
i have the table **wposts** for a multilevel menu in laravel and posts in the same time. The fields of the table are:

```
- id
- parentpost (id of parent post)
- title
- porder (order of posts in the same menu)
```

In the Controller i have the function **getwposts** to get the posts using recursion to have a multilevel menu.

```
private function getwposts($parentid = 0,$wposts = []){

    foreach(Wpost::where('parentpost', $parentid)->orderby('porder')->get() as $pwpost)
    {
        echo $pwpost->id.'-' ;
        $wposts[$pwpost->id] = $this->getwposts($pwpost->id,$wposts);
    }
return $wposts;    
}
```

In the same Controller after that, i have a function called **preview** that renders the view

```
public function preview($templ){

   $pwposts = \App\Wpost::with('parent')->get();

    $pwposts= $this->getwposts(0,[]);
    dd($pwposts);
    return view('templates.$templ1,compact('pwposts'));
}
```

I am almost there. The wright order of the tabble is

[image]

but the results are

[image]

Although with echo i see the correct order of the records in the tree view there isn't ok. 
My model is

```
 namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Wpost extends Model
 {
    protected $fillable = 
   ['parentpost','title','body','author','storeid','porder','haskids'];
   protected $table = 'wposts';

   public function children(){
       return $this->hasmany(Wpost::class, 'parentpost');
   }   

   public function parent(){
       return $this->belongsTo(Wpost::class, 'parentpost');
   }
 }
```

I am stacked. Can you help me?
thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a database-driven multi-level navigation menu using Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305111/how-to-create-a-database-driven-multi-level-navigation-menu-using-laravel)

Comment: post ur Model code too.

Comment: i edited and post my model too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://github.com/etrepat/baum

I used, i feel so good

Comment: there is a lot of theory in this and i dont have the time to test it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your Model add `$with = ['children']`

```
 namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Wpost extends Model
 {
    protected $fillable = 
   ['parentpost','title','body','author','storeid','porder','haskids'];
   protected $table = 'wposts';
   protected $with = ['children'];



   public function children(){
       return $this->hasmany(Wpost::class, 'parentpost');
   }   

   public function parent(){
       return $this->belongsTo(Wpost::class, 'parentpost');
   }
 }
```

Now if you want to get the childs in a recursive way you can use.

```
   $pwposts = \App\Wpost::with('children')->get();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i dont understand the point of the addings. I can use -with- in the syntax as i defined the relations in the model but it doesnt change anything .

Comment: `   $pwposts = \App\Wpost::with('children')->get(); ` this line will return all the data of your table in recursivly

Comment: `$with = ['children'];` will return the children in every request

Comment: i added -with- in the getwposts function and became like this  foreach(Wpost::with('children')->where('parentpost', $parentid)->where('storeid',$id)->orderby('porder')->get() as $pwpost)

Comment: `$with = ['children'];` did you used this in your model?

Comment: as you can see in the results it returns the results the children but not exactly wrifht

Comment: yes and gave me error. $with is used as a variable?

Comment: use `protected $with = ['children']`

Comment: i used and nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
| id | parend_id | name     | url                 |

| 1  |     0     | Level 1  | /level_one          |

| 2  |     1     | Sublevel | /level_one/sublevel |

| 3  |     0     | Level 2  | /level_two          |
```

Model

```
public function children() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Menus', 'parent_id', 'id');
}

public static function tree() {
    return static::with(implode('.', array_fill(0, 100, 'children')))->where('parent_id', '=', '0')->get();
}
```

Controller

```
$components = new Component;
try {
     $menu = $components->tree();
} catch (Exception $e) {}
return response()->json($menu);
```